# IndexedDB: limit selected fields of retrieving object

Tags: indexeddb

While getting object(s) from indexeddb is it possible to limit a set of fields being retrieved (not to fetch a whole data piece)? I believe an actual task when you have large objects in store, but need only small part of data for a particular operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, according to the IndexedDB spec you'll always get the full object, see: [3.4.2 Object Store Retrieval Operation](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-steps-for-retrieving-a-value-from-an-object-store).

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround it's possible to define a key on those fields and then do getAllKeys